# VBA Code to Search for Element on Website and Repeat Search

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am fairly new to VBA and web scraping, but have been reading a lot trying to learn.

I have a long list of addresses in column A of an Excel file. I would like to like to search each of these addresses on the Website http://www.parkopedia.com. This website finds the closest parking and cost based on a given address.

Based on the results, I would like to pull the inner text of two Span tags. This inner text represents the cost of the closest parking and the distance to the parking.

```
    <div class="LocationListItem__searchDetails">
     <div class="LocationDetailsSearchDetails">
      <div class="LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail">
       <span class="LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail__value">Free</span>
       <span class="LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail__label">2 hours</span>
      </div>
     <div class="LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail">
      <span class="LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail__value">20 </span>
```

In this case I would like to pull "Free" and "20" into columns B and C of my spreadsheet. But it appears they both have the same Class name of "LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail"

I have about 1500 results to search, so if possible using xmlHTTP would be preferred.

The first address that I am searching is "10 herrmann place new york 10710"

Below is the code that I have tried far. For right now I have the URL entered directly into the code rather than pulling from the Excel file. I will figure out how to get the correct URL to pull once I can get the correct data to be scraped from the site. The data in B2 is currently blank so that it only pulls the base URL with nothing else on the end.

The issue that I seem to be having is finding a way to get the below line to work correctly.

```
GetParkingData = html.getFirstSpanWithClass('LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail__value').innerText
```

**Module**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
Dim http As clsHTTP, sResponse As String, lastRow As Long, groupResults(), i As Long, html As HTMLDocument
Set html = New HTMLDocument
Set http = New clsHTTP
Const BASE_URL As String = "https://en.parkopedia.com/parking/locations/10_herrmann_place_new_york_10710_united_states_1jegdr72zr6xf2yc83/?arriving=202107131800&leaving=2021071320000"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case lastRow
    Case 1
        Exit Sub
    Case 2
        ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("B2").Value
    Case Else
        arr = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Value
    End Select

    ReDim groupResults(1 To lastRow - 1)

    With http
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Len(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1)) > Len(BASE_URL) Then
                sResponse = .GetHTML(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1))
                html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
                groupResults(i) = .GetParkingData(html)
                sResponse = vbNullString: html.body.innerHTML = vbNullString
            End If
        Next
    End With
    For i = LBound(groupResults) To UBound(groupResults)
        .Cells(i + 1, "C") = groupResults(i)
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Class ClsHTTP**

```
Option Explicit
Private http As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetHTML(ByVal URL As String) As String
Dim sResponse As String
With http
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    GetHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With
End Function

Public Function GetParkingData(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As String
On Error GoTo errhand:
 GetParkingData = html.getFirstSpanWithClass('LocationDetailsSearchDetails__detail__value').innerText
Exit Function
errhand:
GetParkingData = "Not Found"
End Function
```

Thank you all very much! Please forgive anything that seems novice, I am trying to teach myself VBA and web scraping.

Comment: Welcome to SO, we don't write code for you so please edit your question with your attempt first, tell us what's not working and we will take it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code that I have tried that seems the most promising is above, however, it returns "Not Found" (What I coded in case a given value cannot be located, the script would continue to run with the next value) for the data each time. I believe that this should return the value "free" but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: I won't have my pc to look at it for most of today but based on the limited time I have, the information seems to return in json format and you have to do all the calculation on your own from the return data (e.g. whether it's free since it's based on the arriving/leaving time).

It might be a long process to get it right (at least to me!)

Comment: 1. Change this line in `clsHttp`: `GetHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)` to `GetHTML = .responseText`.

2. in `clsHttp`'s `GetParkingData` function: Swap `'` to `"`. 

3. Now you should be able to look through the HTML document, as I mentioned earlier the data are stored in a very long JSON so you need to extract it from the HTML document (it's in a `div` element with `App` id) and process it. Look into [JSONConverter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to help you with that.

Please post a new question on any specific issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed. After extracting the JSON I was able to locate the elements that I wanted to extract. I had to do a little bit of reverse engineering to figure out the calculations and various values but got it working.

Comment: Bravo!! Glad to know you did it :D